# Error when compiling Qt project. The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2

Tags: c++, qt

I'm brand new to Qt and I tried to build a new project. I searched around and people seem to have similar problems but none of the solutions worked for me. I made New Project > Application > Qt widgets Application > created "Tester" file in /Volumes/MATT'S EHD/Qt  > Kit: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 clang 64bit

I build it and this is my output:

```
sh: line 0: cd: /Volumes/MATTS\ EHD/Qt/build-Tester-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_clang_64bit-Debug && /Volumes/MATT\S EHD/Qt/5.8/clang_64/bin/uic: 
No such file or directory




/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [main.o] Error 2
11:43:23: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Tester (kit: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

There's some other output but these are what's outputting in red and I'm assuming what's giving me issues. I haven't changed the file at all. I'm just trying to build it to see if it works and it doesn't. I'm running on OSX and everything is stored on my external hard drive. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it *really* say `MATT\S EHD` after the &&?  If so, that's your problem.  It should be `MATTS\ EHD`.  (You need to escape the space, not the S.  It it doesn't say that USE COPY-PASTE NOT RETYPING when copying errors.

Comment: It actually says MATT\S EHD. And I made a new project with a path to my internal HD. The first error is gone but it's still giving me the second error.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error message complains about a missing matching (in that case closing) single quote, I strongly suspect your “MATT'S EHD” directory is a problem. That’s not too surprising because build systems in the C and C++ world are notoriously crappy when it comes to handling paths with spaces and/or quote characters.

Try a spaceless and quoteless path, not only for your project but also for your complete toolchain, especially the Qt installation. If you can’t or dont want to move your toolchain you can also try to backslash escape all special characters in Qt Creator’s “Build & Run” options. Should work theoretically, but I’ve never tried it in practice.

Comment: I made a new project and stored it directly onto my HD. The first error is gone but the second remains: /bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [Newtest.app/Contents/Info.plist] Error 2
12:02:08: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Newtest (kit: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"

Comment: There’s still a single quote somewhere. See the update to the answer. If you have `CONFIG += silent` anywhere if your .pro file(s) remove it to see the full compiler command lines when building. Might help to find where the quote is hidden.